# TypeError: NoneType returned despite calling a TypeError exception

Tags: python, typeerror

I'm searching a nested dictionary for keys and returning values. I've set up each search with a multiple exception line as follows:

```
try:
    accounts_category = json_data['primaryTopic']['Accounts']['AccountCategory']
except (KeyError, TypeError) as e:
    accounts_category = ''
```

once I've completed the searches, I'm combining the strings and a pipe delimiter as follows:

```
line = H + '|' + vn_id + '|' + sn_id + '|' + supplier_name + '\n'
```

However, I'm getting a TypeError when I try to combine the variables.

```
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, NoneType found
```

My script works if I add an `if` statement:

```
try:
    accounts_next_due_date = json_data['primaryTopic']['Accounts']['NextDueDate']
    if accounts_next_due_date:
        pass
    else:
        accounts_next_due_date = 'e'
except (KeyError, TypeError) as e:
    accounts_next_due_date = 'e'
```

But this seems like a duplication to me, where am I going wrong?

Comment: How does the `line = ...` code fit into the main code you've posted? Can you post the full traceback too please?

Comment: It's not clear what line is raising the error. Please provide more detail...

Comment: Before `line = ....` insert `print(H, vn_id, sn_id, supplier_name)`, and see which of them is `None`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I'm hearing you say is that you execute this code:

```
try:
    accounts_category = json_data['primaryTopic']['Accounts']['AccountCategory']
except (KeyError, TypeError) as e:
    accounts_category = ''
```

And then later `accounts_category` (or some other variable you have handled this way) is `None`, not `''`.

Obviously, this is happening because there is no error being raised. Instead, `json_data['primaryTopic']['Accounts']['AccountCategory']` (or whatever) is in fact `None` (that is, `null` in the original JSON).

The easiest way to avoid this is to use the `or` keyword to add a default value if the value is "false-ish," like so:

```
accounts_category = json_data['primaryTopic']['Accounts']['AccountCategory'] or ''
```

You could also do this when you *use* the value:

```
line = "%s|%s|%s|%s\n" % (H, vn_id, sn_id, supplier_name or '')
```

As a bonus, since it doesn't seem like this is actually raising an error, you may be able to get rid of all the `try/except` boilerplate. If you do still need it, for the love of God please write a function to do it rather than copying and pasting the code umpteen times! For example:

```
def jsonfield(jsonobj, default, *names):
    try:
        for name in names:
             jsonobj = jsonobj[name]
        return jsonobj or default
    except (TypeError, KeyError):
        return default

accounts_category = json_field(json_data, "", "primaryTopic", "Accounts", "AccountCategory")
```

Comment: What if `json_data['primaryTopic']['Accounts']['AccountCategory']` is the integer `0` or a falsy value other than `None`? Similar for your otherwise handy function.

Comment: You would probably want to use `or 0` instead on a field that's supposed to be numeric.

Comment: Kindall thanks very much for this, I'd been struggling with setting up a function because the depth of the nesting changes a lot and I'd struggled with passing the right values to the function. So you've helped a great deal.

Answer (score 1):

> But this seems like a duplication to me

Yes, it is. To avoid it, simply init `accounts_next_due_date` as `None` and add a `finally` clause:

```
accounts_next_due_date = None

try:
    accounts_next_due_date = json_data['primaryTopic']['Accounts']['NextDueDate']
except (KeyError, TypeError):
    pass # or log the error
finally:
    if accounts_next_due_date is None:
        accounts_next_due_date = "e"
```

The `finally` clause it will work if a `KeyError` or `TypeError` is raised, or if `json_data['primaryTopic']['Accounts']['NextDueDate']` is `None`. So no duplicated code.

Comment: A little explanation would go a long way. Otherwise we're forced to do a character-by-character diff of your code with the code in the question.

Comment: @BryanOakley: I modified the answer.

Answer (score 0):

In Python 2, attempting to concatenate a unicode string with `None` raises `TypeError`:

```
>>> u'abcd' + None
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, NoneType found
```

So that's where the problem is manifested. The root cause though is that `json_data` can have a key with a `None` value. Here's a simplified example:

```
>>> import json
>>> data = json.loads('{"a": 1, "b": null}')
{u'a': 1, u'b': None}
>>> b = data['b']
>>> b is None
True
```

This does not cause any exception to be raised, and `None` can therefore be bound to one or more of the variables that you are using to construct the `line` string. You can fix it with this:

```
accounts_category = json_data['primaryTopic']['Accounts']['AccountCategory']
if accounts_category is None:
    accounts_category = u''
```

And you can generalise that into a function so that it can be applied to other keys from your JSON data.

Also, you can use `str.join()` to better perform that concatenation of your strings:

```
line = u'|'.join((H, vn_id, sn_id, supplier_name)
```